# How to make an android application like level meter

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an application like spirit level in android and i am moving bubble on the screen with the help of accelerometer readings. I am unable to stop bubble movement and it goes out of the screen . Can any one please guide me how to stop the bubble movement .

Comment: You may want to correct the typo in your title... At first glance, it makes your question VERY ambiguous...

Comment: Hi perhaps see this example for bubble level https://github.com/jwpaine/Spirit-Level

Comment: Depending on the layout you're using, you may be able to declare it in your activity and set it to the activity's instance. Use the methods for the layout's size to limit the movement of the bubble

Comment: Actually i am trying to move bubble inside an image view. And i have defined x and y limits for the bubble it is not working properly. I have tested it on different devices but on some devices bubble not moving properly and it goes out of the parent image view.

Comment: @SaadUllah If possible, please post your code. by putting ```` above and below it, it will give the code its own section from the rest of your post.